# How to select elements with only whitespace with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm having an issue selecting elements with only whitespace.

Given the html: `<html><body><p> </p></body></html>`

Using :empty does not select the p I'm assuming because there is a text node of " " within it

However, `:matchesOwn(^\\s+$)` won't select it either because it seems that JSoup does a `trim()` on the text before testing it against the regex pattern.

`:matchesOwn(^$)` will select it, but also selects elements with no text nodes that aren't empty

Maybe I'm missing something?

`:matchesOwn` shouldn't trim at all as it is using a regular expression and the whole text should be evaluated

Comment: Without some kind of workaround this wont work (at least with the current version). As you have said: the blank is trimed - can be checked with `element.text().isEmpty()` which will return `true`. The best solution is to ***open an issue*** at [**Jsoup's Github issues**](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues).

Comment: @ollo Here is a workaround involving Jsoup API: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35012778/363573.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors can only match a specific kind of node: **element**. Selectors can't find comments or text nodes. For finding elements with only whitespace, we have to rely on the Jsoup API.

We'll look for nodes having one unique text node only child. This unique text node must match the following regex `^\s+$`. To get the (untrimmed) text we'll call the `TextNode#getWholeText` method.

Here is how to do it:

```
String html = "<html><body><div><p> </p><p> </p><span>\n\t\n   </span></div><span></span></body></html>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

final Matcher onlyWhitespaceMatcher = Pattern.compile("^\\s+$").matcher("");
new NodeTraversor(new NodeVisitor() {

    @Override
    public void head(Node node, int depth) {
        List<Node> childNodes = node.childNodes();
        // * We're looking for nodes with one child only otherwise we move on
        if (childNodes.size() != 1) {
            return;
        }

        // * This unique child node must be a TextNode
        Node uniqueChildNode = childNodes.get(0);
        if (uniqueChildNode instanceof TextNode == false) {
            return;
        }

        // * This unique TextNode must be whitespace only
        if (onlyWhitespaceMatcher.reset(((TextNode) uniqueChildNode).getWholeText()).matches()) {
            System.out.println(node.nodeName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
        // void
    }
}).traverse(doc);
// Instead of traversing the whole document,
// we could narrow down the search to its body only with doc.body()
```

#### OUTPUT

```
p
p
span
```